# Changed ip now cannot start MySql

Tags: mysql, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a public virtual machine that I had to change the ip address now I cannot get MySql to start.

The event viewer shows these message:

```
Server hostname (bind-address): 'xxx.xxx.xxx.249'; port: 3306
```

Then I get these 3 errors:

```
Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port: No such file or directory

Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?

Faulting application name: mysqld.exe, version: 5.5.42.0, time stamp: 0x54ac4a9a
Faulting module name: mysqld.exe, version: 5.5.42.0, time stamp: 0x54ac4a9a
Exception code: 0x80000003
Fault offset: 0x000000000021fac2
Faulting process id: 0x23cc
Faulting application start time: 0x01d0c7f3f4d0a87d
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\mysqld.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\mysqld.exe
Report Id: 3b931dcc-33e7-11e5-80dd-00155dbffa04
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

I noticed that in the my.ini that it had the client and server bound to 3306:

```
[client]

port=3306

[mysql]

default-character-set=utf8

# SERVER SECTION
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
#
# The following options will be read by the MySQL Server. Make sure that
# you have installed the server correctly (see above) so it reads this 
# file.
#
[mysqld]

# The TCP/IP Port the MySQL Server will listen on
port=3306
```

I wasn't sure if this was right but I did not change it.

I did do a `netstat -an` but I do not show anything on port 3306.

I have restarted the server to verify it wasn't already resolved.

What else should I check? I didn't think changing an ip address would have this big of a consequence on MySql.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here:

https://serverfault.com/questions/35637/mysql-dying-on-startup

This is what I did and it worked for those in need later:

> I had this error after running out of harddisk space. I finally solved
>   it by deleting ib*.tmp files from C:\Windows\temp which were causing
>   the startup to fail, even for data directories that were previously
>   working.

If you cannot find the temp directory, show hidden folders.